# showModalDialog() being run even though the if() gate to it isn't evaluating to true

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I've got a program that has to run entirely in App Script (the users using it don't have install rights on their computers for addons). The program makes business quotes, and a bunch of other things based on the information in the quotes.

I need to make copies of the quotes to save them, then authorize the code to run on those copies so that if changes need to be made, they can be.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  var authStatus = authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus();
  var authRequired = (authStatus == ScriptApp.AuthorizationStatus.REQUIRED);

  Logger.log(authStatus);
  Logger.log(authRequired);

  if ( authRequired ) {
    Logger.log('Authorization required');
    var authScript = '<script type="text/javascript">'+
                       'function openAuthWindow() {'+
                         'window.open("'+authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl()+'");'+
                       '}'+
                     '</script>';
    var alert = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebarHeadOpen')
        .append(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(authScript).getContent())
        .append(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('authorizeAlert').getContent());
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(alert, 'Authorization Required');
  } else {
    var frontend = e.source;
    initialize(frontend);
  }
}
```

My problem is that the code within "if ( authRequired ) { ... }" is still run, even when it shouldn't. (i.e. when authStatus is NOT_REQUIRED and authRequired is false) What's more, though the log should show "Authorization required" when that code is run, it doesn't. The only lines run from that statement are the "var authScript = ...;" line, the "var alert = ...;" line, and the "SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog();" line. Which is the thing I'm trying to make *not* happen. Is there a way to do that?

For reference, this is what alert.html looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function openAuthWindow() {
      window.open("'+authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl()+'");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Please authorize this copy of the form to run.<br>
    <br>
    Without authorization, it will not do anything automatically.<br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Review Permissions" onclick="google.script.host.close(); openAuthWindow(); google.script.run.runInstall();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

(Also, is there a simpler way to prompt for authorization? Maybe even one to just programmatically obtain it, without prompting the user? I've been looking for a week, and haven't found one.)

Comment: Is this a Web App?  How does `onOpen()` run?  From a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this related [issue 677 - Allow end users to provide OAuth credentials](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677) posted in google-apps-script-issues and based from that thread there are workarounds which you can also try and one was posted in GitHub - [OAuthService for Google Apps Script](https://github.com/leviwheatcroft/OAuthService) wherein the developer wrapped oAuth flow up in a library which you can also add to your own script.

Solution given in this SO post - [Google API Authorization when 'Executing the app as me.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293204/google-api-authorization-when-executing-the-app-as-me) regarding authorization within google apps script might also help.